# Custom-Webpart not working on a second site collection

Tags: deployment

I've got a custom webpart that's working great on different MOSS-servers.
Now I tried to use this webpart on a 2nd sitecollection (B) on a server. It's already running on sitecollection A.
What I did:
The wsp-file is present on the server, so I just used: %STSADM% -o deploysolution -n xyz.wsp -local -url http://localhost:12345 in the servers console. I activated the webpart's feature and so on. When I try to add it to a site I get so following message:

***A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe.***

I also tried to change the webconfig of the 2nd site collection to trustlevel:Full, but nothin changed.
Rebooting IIS and the server itself didn't help, too.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed the Problem..........

The webpart-page was not correctly checked-in in sharepoint designer. That's why the page was not working well.

After checking out and in the webpartpage again. Everything worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

is the second Site Collection within another Web Application than the first one? If yes check if the DLL behind the Web Part is in the GAC or was a BIN-Deployment. If second check if the DLL is in the right place of the second Web Application as well.

Comment: Each SiteCollection is using it's own WebApplication as the same user.
The dll is in both bin-directories.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the SafeControls section of the web.config in your second web application? There should be a SafeControl entry for your web part's namespace.

Deploying the wsp 'should' do this automatically, but just in case...

Comment: Yes, I checked these entries and can't find any differences to those in the other SiteCollection.

Answer (score 0):

I got additional information.

I checked both webconfigs and the only difference is the "machine-key". The machine key must be different....Am I right?

Another try was undeploying the webpart and redeploying only to SiteCollection B. When trying to add the webpart to the site I get: "Unable to add selected webpart(s). XY: Cannot import the XY web part.